# How do I limit column re-sizing to view-port size / prevent overflow

Tags: slickgrid

I have seen from grooveshark implementation that is is possible to limit the column re-sizing to view-port size ( prevent scroll ) any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `forceFitColumns` option when initialising the grid.

```
var grid;
var columns = [ ... columns stuff
var options = { ... other options,
                forceFitColumns: true
              };

var data = [ ... data stuff

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```